# How do I manage two closure tables for one resource in SQLite3

Tags: database-design, sqlite

I hope this isn't too specific for SO. I am finding it a learning experience.

On the high level I am writing an JSON:API interface to a sqlite3 database for storing user comments. With JSON:API a flat list of resources can be listed in the `included` section with each resource providing a `relationships` which could point back to other comments it seemed natural to use a closure table to represent comment threading and comment likes.

I started with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  author TEXT,
  body TEXT,
  created_at DATE,
  email TEXT,
  href TEXT,
  ip_address TEXT,
  post_id TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE comment_threads (
  parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  child_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (parent_id, child_id)
);

CREATE TABLE comment_likes (
  comment_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ip_address TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (comment_id, ip_address)
);
```

My thought was that I could select the comments by `post_id` then grab the comments from the `comment_thread` table and build out a flat list of comments to put into the `included` section of the JSON:API output.

The concern is that this means many SQL queries and manually rebuilding the comments' relationships. My worry is this seems a bit naive to perform multiple SQL queries for each resource.

How do I (or **can** I) perform this in one (or fewer) SQL statement(s)?

I've been able to accomplish this with the comment likes using:

```
SELECT c.id,c.author,c.body,c.created_at,c.href,c.post_id,
       COUNT(cl.comment_id) AS likes
FROM comments AS c
JOIN comment_likes AS cl ON c.id == cl.comment_id
WHERE c.post_id == 'test'
ORDER BY c.created_at ASC;
```

But I am unsure how I could expand this to make the table look like:

```
| id | author | body            | created_at | href | post_id | likes | comments   |
|====|========|=================|============|======|=========|=======|============|
|  1 | Bob    | test comment    | 1990-12-17 |      | test    |     1 | array(2,3) |
|  2 | Jane   | test comment 2  | 1990-12-18 |      |         |     0 | array()    |
|  3 | Jill   | test comment 3  | 1990-12-19 |      |         |     0 | array(4,5) |
|  4 | Bortus | test comment 4  | 1990-12-20 |      |         |     2 | array()    |
|  5 | John   | test comment 5  | 1990-12-21 |      |         |     0 | array()    |
```

Is this even possible?

### Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (1,'Bob','test comment','1990-12-17','foo@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.1','test');
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (2,'Jane','test comment 2','1990-12-18','foo2@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.2',NULL);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (3,'Jill','test comment 3','1990-12-19','foo3@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.3',NULL);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (4,'Bortus','test comment 4','1990-12-20','foo4@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.4',NULL);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (5,'John','test comment 5','1990-12-21','foo5@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.5',NULL);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (6,'Spock','test comment 6','1990-12-22','foo6@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.6','test2');
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (7,'Jim','test comment 7','1990-12-23','foo7@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.7',NULL);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (8,'Beverly','test comment 8','1990-12-24','foo8@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.8',NULL);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (9,'Stacy','test comment 9','1990-12-25','foo9@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.9',NULL);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (10,'Alice','test comment 10','1990-12-26','foo10@example.com',NULL,'1.1.1.10',NULL);

INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (3, 5);
INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (6, 7);
INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (7, 8);
INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (8, 9);
INSERT INTO comment_threads VALUES (9, 10);

INSERT INTO comment_likes VALUES (1, '1.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO comment_likes VALUES (4, '1.1.1.2');
INSERT INTO comment_likes VALUES (4, '1.1.1.5');
INSERT INTO comment_likes VALUES (6, '1.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO comment_likes VALUES (6, '1.1.1.4');
INSERT INTO comment_likes VALUES (8, '1.1.1.1');
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data to populate your tables with (as insert statements for easy copy and pasting) that can be used to get your desired output?

Comment: @Shawn Sample data added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do in one statement - you just need a couple of correlated subqueries in the values that are being selected to calculate the like count and child comment list columns.

Note: Since you're turning this into JSON anyways, the following uses a JSON array for the comments column to save a step, using the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension. If your sqlite setup wasn't compiled with that enabled, you can do something similar with [group_concat()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat).

```
SELECT id, author, body, created_at, href, post_id
     , (SELECT count(*) FROM comment_likes AS l WHERE c.id = l.comment_id) AS likes
     , (SELECT json_group_array(t.child_id) FROM comment_threads AS t WHERE c.id = t.parent_id) AS comments
FROM comments AS c
ORDER BY created_at;
```

produces

```
id          author      body          created_at  href        post_id     likes       comments  
----------  ----------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Bob         test comment  1990-12-17              test        1           [2,3]     
2           Jane        test comment  1990-12-18                          0           []        
3           Jill        test comment  1990-12-19                          0           [4,5]     
4           Bortus      test comment  1990-12-20                          2           []        
5           John        test comment  1990-12-21                          0           []        
6           Spock       test comment  1990-12-22              test2       2           [7]       
7           Jim         test comment  1990-12-23                          0           [8]       
8           Beverly     test comment  1990-12-24                          1           [9]       
9           Stacy       test comment  1990-12-25                          0           [10]      
10          Alice       test comment  1990-12-26                          0           []
```

---

Edit: If you want just a comment with a particular `post_id` and its reply thread instead of every comment, [recursive CTEs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) come into play:

```
WITH one_thread AS
 (SELECT id, author, body, created_at, href, post_id FROM comments WHERE post_id = 'test'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.author, c.body, c.created_at, c.href, c.post_id
  FROM one_thread AS o
  JOIN comment_threads AS t ON o.id = t.parent_id
  JOIN comments AS c ON t.child_id = c.id)
SELECT id, author, body, created_at, href, post_id
     , (SELECT count(*) FROM comment_likes AS l WHERE c.id = l.comment_id) AS likes
     , (SELECT json_group_array(t.child_id) FROM comment_threads AS t WHERE c.id = t.parent_id) AS comments
FROM one_thread AS c
ORDER BY created_at;
```

That gives just

```
id          author      body          created_at  href        post_id     likes       comments  
----------  ----------  ------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Bob         test comment  1990-12-17              test        1           [2,3]     
2           Jane        test comment  1990-12-18                          0           []        
3           Jill        test comment  1990-12-19                          0           [4,5]     
4           Bortus      test comment  1990-12-20                          2           []        
5           John        test comment  1990-12-21                          0           []
```